# Select Fields, count() group by on eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do a query like:

`SELECT agenda_id, data, count(*) FROM marcacoes group by data, agenda_id`

I try `$agendas = Marcacao::select(['data', 'agenda_id'])->groupBy('data', 'agenda_id')->count();` but the result is only the field `count`. The fields `data` and `agenda_id` is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a raw statement:

```php
Marcacao::select('data', 'agenda_id', DB::raw('count(*)'))
    ->groupBy('data', 'agenda_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions. It tells the query builder that `count(*)` is not the name of a column but a raw expression.

Answer (score 1):

your request gives you just the number of `agendas` because you use `count` method.

if you want `agandas` data you request should be like this :

`$agendas = Marcacao::select(['data', 'agenda_id'])->groupBy('data', 'agenda_id')->get();`.

then when you want to get the number of your `$agenda`, you should just count `$agandas` collection like this :

`$numberOfAgandas = $agandas->count();`

Answer (score 1):

Because you call the `count` method this will return just one value and `int` precisely which is the number of element that correspond to your `MacMarcacao::select(['data', 'agenda_id'])->groupBy('data', 'agenda_id')` you will not get all other fields because the count method return a value not a `Collection` like you are expecting.

You must firstly retrieve your record and after that you can count the method cound

```
$agendas = MacMarcacao::select(['data', 'agenda_id'])->groupBy('data', 'agenda_id')->get()
```

After that you can count number of records in your `$agendas` which is a an object of type `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

```
$numberOfAgendas = $agendas->count();
```